# Ace Editor displaying distorted XML text (Chrome)

Tags: xml, google-chrome, ace-editor, word-wrap

I am using Ace editor to display XML text on a website. A lot of the time it works quite well, but sometimes it wraps (distorts ??) the text in a weird way if the line can't fit. This seems to only happen in Google Chrome.[image]

As you can see, the text runs into itself. Here is the original XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en">Fault</faultstring>
        <detail>
          <cause>UnrecoverableClientError</cause>
          <code>SchemaError</code>
          <desc>validation failure for CreateOpenShipmentRequest Error:cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'dateTime'.
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'v13:ShipTimestamp' is not valid.</desc>
        </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is there any way to fix this so that the text wraps nicely?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ace, the best way to handle it is to create a simple example that reproduces the issue and report it to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues

Comment: Wow, for real?? That is genuinely disappointing. I'll have to report it so they are aware.